# SQL Server custom rounding of decimal value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, decimal, rounding

I want to round the decimal value of `5.457845`.

- If the first digit value after decimal is greater than `5` then `5.5`
- If the first digit value after decimal is less than `5` then `5.0`

For example:

```
5.457845 = 5.0
5.684575 = 5.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
select floor(5.457845 * 2) / 2  -- returns 5.0
select floor(5.684575 * 2) / 2  -- returns 5.5
select floor(5.0 * 2) / 2       -- corner case 1 - returns 5.0
select floor(5.4999999 * 2) / 2 -- corner case 2 - returns 5.0
select floor(5.5 * 2) / 2       -- corner case 3 - returns 5.5
select floor(5.9999999 * 2) / 2 -- corner case 4 - returns 5.5
```

Note that this may not work so well for negative numbers:

```
select floor(-5.0 * 2) / 2       -- corner case 5 - returns -5.0
select floor(-5.4999999 * 2) / 2 -- corner case 6 - returns -5.5
select floor(-5.5 * 2) / 2       -- corner case 7 - returns -5.5
select floor(-5.9999999 * 2) / 2 -- corner case 8 - returns -6.0
```

Comment: This is working but it is showing result like 5.500000 but i want exactly 5.5

Comment: Sorry, try something like this `select convert(decimal(9,1), floor(5.457845 * 2) / 2)`.  But it usually doesn't matter what the output number looks like from a query because where possible you should be formatting for readability at the UI layer, not here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any native function is present to do this. Try this trick

```
DECLARE @num NUMERIC(22, 6) = 5.684575

SELECT Floor(@num) + CASE WHEN Round(@num, 1, 1) % 1 <= 0.5 THEN 0 ELSE 0.5 END
```

**Result :** `5.5`

If the number can be negative then you need use `ABS` function on top of `ROUND` function

```
ABS(Round(@num, 1, 1)) % 1
```